# Unrelated defaults inheritance error for type variables: why?

Tags: java, java-8, type-variables

**Disclaimer**: this is **not** about this case (while error sounds as same): [class inherits unrelated defaults for spliterator() from types java.util.Set and java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746948/class-inherits-unrelated-defaults-for-spliterator-from-types-java-util-set-and)

and here is why:

consider two interfaces (in package "`a`")

```
interface I1 {
    default void x() {}
}

interface I2 {
    default void x() {}
}
```

It is definitely clear to me why we can not declare such class as:

```
abstract class Bad12 implements I1, I2 {
}
```

**(!)** But I can not understand this restriction with reference to **type variables**:

```
class A<T extends I1&I2> {
    List<T> makeList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

with error: `class java.lang.Object&a.I1&a.I2 inherits unrelated defaults for x() from types a.I1 and a.I2`.

Why I can not define such type variable? Why `java` cares about unrelated defaults in this case? What such type variable could "break"?

**UPDATE:** Just for clarification. I can create several classes of the form:

```
class A1 implements I1, I2 {
    public void x() { };
}

class A2 implements I1, I2 {
    public void x() { };
}
```

and even

```
abstract class A0 implements I1, I2 {
    @Override
    public abstract void x();
}
```

and so on. Why I can not declare special kind of type variable for such group of classes?

**UPD-2:** BTW I didn't find any distinct restriction for this case in JLS. It would be nice to confirm your answer with references to JLS.

**UPD-3:** Some of users told that this code is compiled well in Eclipse. I can not check it, but I checked with `javac` and got this error:

```
 error: class INT#1 inherits unrelated defaults for x() from types I1 and I2
class A<T extends I1&I2> {
        ^
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,I1,I2
1 error
```

Comment: My guess is that this is a compiler bug. The compiler seems to create these 'capture classes'  for type variables (also where `capture#1` in type errors with wildcard types comes from). Apparently, it performs class checks on them, one of which is this conflicting default method check.

Comment: NB. Compiles on eclipse.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Wow. I use `Intellij IDEA`. Will try with javac...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just cheked it with "pure" `javac`: same error: `ain.java:10: error: class INT#1 inherits unrelated defaults for x() from types I1 and I2
class A<T extends I1&I2> {
        ^
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,I1,I2
1 error`

Comment: One way to think about this without the details of the implementation is to consider the converse. Why should it be meaningful to have a type variable that allows invalid types? That seems to go against the purpose of static typing. Your valid cases are a subset of the possible cases, but not all the possible cases are valid. Seems reasonable for the compiler to whine.

Comment: try compiling `interface II extends I1, I2` with and without specifying a `default void x() {}`

Comment: @Clashsoft Good idea. I just submitted bug report to `Oracle`. Will see the result.

Comment: If that is considered a bug, I'm going to eat my collection of holiday hats.

Comment: @pvg And what about my update #1: there is a group of classes which I can not reflect in terms of type variables. Why?

Comment: @pvg In any case I've evaluated your joke :) LOL

Comment: @pvg if it isn't a bug, why eclipse compiler (which is different from oracle's one) compiles it well?

Comment: @Andremoniy My answer was wrong because any specific implementation of `<T extends I1&I2>` is going to have to implement `void x()`, or it won't compile.


Your `A1` and `A2` are not using the `default void x()` declared in `I1` and `I2`. They are using overridden definitions of x() (that are exactly the same). Try modifying those implementations to be different, they will still compile right? These overridden implementations are what you cannot reflect in a type variable.

Comment: I have no idea how it could possibly work in Eclipse nor can you pay me enough to trudge through all the voodoo in JLS on generics. But I think the burden is really on you to explain how what you expect is reasonable - the existence of valid instances in a type description doesn't mean the type description itself is valid. The one you want is 'implements I1 and I2 and also provides a concrete implementation of x'. Unfortunately there is no way to express that.

Comment: Oh a couple of other things - apparently Eclipse can compile invalid code, search SO for lots of Q/A on the (strange) details. It's telling, though, that IntelliJ's static analysis also identifies this as an error which suggest this is not some unspecified peculiarity of javac.

Comment: @pvg I'm absolutely agree with you about eclipse&intellij features. Let's just find explanation in JLS, and then distinct understanding why :)

Comment: @pvg And I can not agree about *"the existence of valid instances in a type description doesn't mean the type description itself is valid"*. I'm sorry, but this phrase looks like contradiction to itself. If valid type exists, why I can not define it in terms of type variable? Isn't it a confusion?

Comment: No i don't think it's contradictory at all. Here's what happens - you are saying 'compiler, I'd like you to verify this argument matches this particular type description'. The compiler replies 'I can't do that, Dave, this description contains invalid types'. Your reply is 'so what, some of them _could_ be valid!'. That's not static typechecking.

Comment: @pvg Please post a video of the hat eating!  The type constraint <T extends I1&I2> is entirely valid; it means "A can only be instantiated with a type that is a subtype of I1 and I2.  And the compiler cannot prove that no such type exists, because in fact it is possible to construct such types.

Comment: @BrianGoetz hah, I'll have to petition SO to return them to me for the ritual. So you're saying the criterion is compiler has to be able to prove no such type can exist at all rather than some do not exist. That doesn't seem entirely obvious to me but that's neither here nor there. Are there cases you can think of outside default methods in which this sort of thing pops up?

Comment: @pvg The bounds <X extends Y&Z> is simply a statement that it is only legal to instantiate A with a type that is a subtype of Y and of Z.  The compiler will balk if Y&Z is not a legal type (e.g., Y and Z are both classes), and is entitled to balk if it can prove no such type can exist (e.g., Y is a final class that does not implement Z).  But the bound I1&I2 is valid.  The default methods should not get involved in this computation -- thats just a bug.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Could the bug-report-review be converted into bug-report with your moderation assistance? Review ID: JI-9028332

Comment: @BrianGoetz yep, makes sense. I thought of it more like the definition of a set. If some of the elements are bogus, the whole thing is bogus.

Comment: @Andremoniy Turns out to be a duplicate of this existing bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7120669

Comment: @BrianGoetz Hmm... Yes it looks like more common description of the problem. In general I agree, but this relates to JLS. But my filling is that described case should be formed as separated javac bug for Java 8.

Comment: In any case, we are waiting for hat-eating video from @pvg :-)

Comment: That other bug report is quite informative (and answers my 'what's a case of this without default methods' question). Dan Smith writes "If you squint, you might see an implicit assertion, sometimes enforced by the compiler, that the imaginary class declaration we use to model membership must be well-formed." which surely sweetens what might have otherwise been a bitter hat-eating. It seems it also confirms the validity of your fundamental question  - "where the hell is this in the spec?"

Comment: @pvg: I can happily declare a type variable as `<T extends String & List<Number>>` despite the fact that there can't be any valid actual type for it.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: the compiler doesn't complain, if `Z` is `final` and doesn't implement `Y`. Just try `<T extends String & List<Number>>`.

Comment: @Holger Didn't say it did!  Said it would be *entitled* to balk in that case.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: shouldn't the behavior be *fixed* regarding whether such construct creates a compile-time error or not? I have some problems with the term "entitled"...

Comment: @Holger I think you mistook my statement about "what would be reasonable from a language design perspective" for a statement about what the specification actually says.  I was trying to illustrate a range of reasonable specification and implementation choices, to help the commenter understand the problem better.  Apparently I confused you, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is simply a bug.  It turns out that the bug starts in the specification, and then spills over into the implementation.  Spec bug is here:  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7120669

The constraint is perfectly valid; it is clearly possible that there exist types T that extend both I1 and I2.  The problem is how we validate the well-formedness of such types.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanics of "intersection types" (a type specified by the *union* of several interfaces) may seem strange at first, especially when paired with the functioning of generics and type erasure. If you introduce several type bounds with interfaces that do not extend each other, only the first is used as the erasure. If you have code like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T> & Iterable<String>>
int f(T t1, T t2) {
    int res = t1.compareTo(t2);
    if (res!=0) return res;
    Iterator<String> s1 = t1.iterator(), s2 = t2.iterator();
    // compare the sequences, etc
}
```

Then the generated bytecode would not be able to use Iterable in the erasure of T. The *actual* erasure of T would be just Comparable, and the generated bytecode would contain casts to Iterable as appropriate (emitting a `checkcast` to Iterable in addition to the usual `invokeinterface` opcode), resulting in code conceptually equivalent to the following, with the only difference that the compiler also checks the `Iterable<String>` bound:

```
public static int f(Comparable t1, Comparable t2) {
    int res = t1.compareTo(t2);
    if (res!=0) return res;
    Iterator s1 = ((Iterable)t1).iterator(), s2 = ((Iterable)t2).iterator();
    // compare the sequences, etc
}
```

The problem in your example with override-equivalent methods in the interfaces is that, even though valid types may exist that conform to your requested type bounds (as stated in the comments), the compiler cannot use that truth in any meaningful way due to the presence of at least one `default` method.

Consider the example class X that implements both I1 and I2 by overriding the defaults with its own method. *If* your type bound asked for `extends X` instead of `extends I1&I2` the compiler would accept it,  erasing T to X and inserting `invokevirtual X.f()` instructions at each usage of f. However, with your type bound, the compiler would erase T to I1. Since the "join type" X is not real in this second case, on each usage of t.f() the compiler would need to insert *either* `invokeinterface I1.f()` or `invokeinterface I2.f()`. Since the compiler cannot possibly insert a call to "X.f()", even when it logically knows that it *is* possible for a type X to implement I1&I2, and that any such X *must* declare that function, it cannot decide between the two interfaces and has to bail out.

In the *specific* case without any `default` methods, the compiler can simple call either function, since in that case it knows that either `invokeinterface` call will unambiguously have been implemented in a single function in any valid X. However, when default methods enter the picture this solution can no longer assumed to produce valid code when partial compilation is taken into account. Consider the following three files:

```
// A.java
public class A {
    public static interface I1 {
        void f();
        // default int getI() { return 1; }
    }
    public static interface I2 {
        void g();
        // default int getI() { return 2; }
    }
}

// B.java
public class B implements A.I1, A.I2 {
    public void f() { System.out.println("in B.f"); }
    public void g() { System.out.println("in B.g"); }
}

// C.java
public class C {
    public static <T extends A.I1 & A.I2> void test(T var) {
        var.f();
        var.g();
        // System.out.println(var.getI());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(new B());
    }
}
```

- A.java is compiled first, with its code as shown, producing "v1.0" of the interfaces A.I1 and A.I2
- B.java is compiled next, generating an (at that point) valid class implementing the interfaces
- C.java can now be compiled, again with its code as shown, and the compiler accepts it. It prints what you would expect.
- The default methods in A.java are uncommented and the file is recompiled (producing "v.1.1" of the interfaces), but B.java is *not* rebuilt against it. This is akin to upgrading the JRE core libraries but not some other library you are using that implements some JRE interfaces.
- Finally, we try to rebuild C.java because we are going to use the fancy new features of the latest JRE. Regardless of whether or not we uncomment the call to getI, the intersection type declaration is rejected by the compiler with the same error you asked about.

*If* the compiler were to accept the intersection type `(A.I1 & A.I2)` as valid when building C.class the second time, it would take the risk that existing classes like B would raise an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` at runtime, since a call to getI anywhere would not be resolved either in B or in Object, and the default method search would find two different default methods. The compiler is protecting you against a possible runtime error by disallowing the offending type bound.

Note, however, that the error may still occur if the bound is replaced by `T extends B`. However, I *would* consider this final point to be a compiler bug, since the compiler can now see that `B implements A.I1, A.I2` with their default methods with override-equivalent signatures, but does not override them, thus ensuring a conflict.

**Major edit**: removed the first (possibly confusing) example and added an explanation+example on why the particular case with defaults is disallowed.

Comment: The statement about the erasure is not correct, as for `<T extends I1&I2>`, the erasure still will be `I1` and not `Object`. If you declared `<T extends Object&I1&I2>`, the erasure was `Object`. But it's correct that the compiler has to make a decision whether it will invoke `I1.x()` or `I2.x()` when `T.x()` is invoked. This situation is the same when both declarations are `abstract` and it should only matter, when the invocation actually happens.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is : Why I can not declare special kind of type variable for such group of classes?

The answer is: because in your group of classes `<T extends I1&I2>` `void x()` has **two** default implementations. Any concrete implementation of the type variable has to override those defaults.

Your A1 and A2 have different (but override-equivalent) definitions of `void x()`.

Your A0 is an overridden definition of `void x()` which replaces the defaults.

```
class A<T extends I1&I2> {
  List<T> makeList() {
      return new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // You can't create an EE to put into A<> which has a default void x()
    new A<EE>();
  }
}
```

[JLS 8.4.8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4)
It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a default method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by C, unless there exists an abstract method declared in a superclass of C and inherited by C that is override-equivalent with the two methods.

[JLS 4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)
A type variable must not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface, or a compile-time error occurs.

[JLS 4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9)
Every intersection type T1 & ... & Tninduces a notional class or interface for the purpose of identifying the members of the intersection type, as follows:

•
For each Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n), let Ci be the most specific class or array type such that Ti <: Ci. Then there must be some Ck such that Ck <: Ci for any i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Sure, I can: `abstract class A0 implements I1, I2 {  public abstract void x(); }`

Comment: OK, so now you are forcing implementations of A0 to override `void x();`. Gee, that's just the same thing as I said.

Comment: in any way, this is not an answer on my question. Look above, even @BrienGoetz told that *<T extends I1&I2> is entirely valid*. You are trying answering on different question, not about my.

Comment: There is valid class `class A1 implements I1, I2 {
    public void x() { };
}`, so it should exist type constant `<T extends I1&I2>`. What you are talking about is not an answer.

Comment: @Andremoniy It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a default method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by C, unless there exists an abstract method declared in a superclass of C and inherited by C that is override-equivalent with the two methods. 


https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4

Comment: You can not in no way understand that question **isn't about type inheritance** but about type variables.

Comment: It's related. A type variable must not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface, or a compile-time error occurs. 

   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

Comment: It is not `different parameterizations of the same generic interface` in my case

Comment: Just to let you know what is JLS 4.4 look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232734/how-to-reproduce-java-compile-runtime-error-for-generic-interface-type-variables

Comment: JLS 4.9 is totally out of topic. All Ck exist. Really, don't take offence. Close, but no cigar.