# Why can IntelliJ detect missing semi-colons and Java compiler can't?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-construction

I was wondering why that's the case. How and why IntelliJ is able to detect missing semi-colons and Java compiler can't? Is there a case where IntelliJ is wrong and there is no way to actually detect missing semicolon?
I read similar question discussing C and C++, there are pointers which complicate things, but Java seems simpler in that matter.

Comment: In what way can the Java compiler not detect missing semi-colons? If they're missing, the code won't compile...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well, the compiler can tell you ";" missing ... or it can give all kinds of misleading messages.

Comment: So if java compiler can detect it, why do we need to use them?

Comment: Why do we need to use a Java compiler to compile Java? Because the JVM runs Java byte code, which is produced by.......wait for it.......a compiler!

Comment: You have provided no evidence that the Java compiler can't detect missing semicolons. Add code that is missing semicolons and still compiles.

Comment: Because you probably want to know that you missed some semicolons in your code *before* you try to build your app, if build takes more than a few seconds ;)

Comment: *Why?* Because the IntelliJ compiler is more *intelligent* than the standard Java compiler, to help provide more meaningful messages when highlighting code errors in the editor. Same goes for Eclipse, since IntelliJ probably uses the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: IntelliJ uses javac by default. But errors are detected by IntelliJ itself, not the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to challenge your premise that a Java compiler cannot detect missing semicolons. I just tried to compile the following code with `javac` from Oracle JDK 8, and it is perfectly able to detect the missing semicolon:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println()
  }
}
```

The compiler error printed is the following:

```
Test.java:3: error: ';' expected
    System.out.println()
                        ^
1 error
```

As you can see, it not only detected the missing semicolon, it was even able to point out exactly *where* it was missing.

Comment: At the bottom of all the turtles, IDEA also uses the compiler api to verify code. For instance, it replicates the rare compiler bug perfectly.

Comment: Does it? I was under the impression that IDEA actually has its own compiler infrastructure, which is the reason why they are sometimes slightly lagging in new language features but is also the reason why such awesome features as pasting Java code into a Scala source file and it automatically being converted into Scala code work. They have a single integrated "IDE compiler" with a single integrated, cross-language semantic tree representation and different frontends. (That's the same technology that underlies JetBrains MPS, I believe.) Or am I completely wrong about that?

Comment: No I don't think you're wrong, I just got the _additional_ impression that they go further if they can from the fact they match bugs perfectly. Now I'm wondering if I'm completely wrong about that, let me try to dig up a specific case.

Comment: They *do* use the platform compiler for code generation (except for Kotlin, where the IDE compiler and the platform compiler are one and the same). Maybe that's what you're thinking about? Or, actually, they use their IDE compiler for online analysis (syntax highlighting, semantic highlighting, autocompletion, quick fixes, refactoring, inline documentation, red squigglies, etc.), the platform compiler for code generation, and they likely use both for static analysis. I think that's the correct way to put it.

Comment: I'm thinking of strange cases like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644237/unrelated-defaults-inheritance-error-for-type-variables-why#comment57037097_34644237
So, to me, it seems fairly strange IDEA replicates this exactly. When I saw that, I assumed they're doing something beyond a kind of 'cleanroom' compiler front-end (which, as you say, has been the core of their IDE tech for ages)

Comment: It might have something to do with what Brian Goetz said in his answer: "It turns out that the bug starts in the specification, and then spills over into the implementation." If the bug is in the spec, then it is possible that independent implementations faithfully replicate the bug exactly. I once read about a security hole about 20 years ago simultaneously in Solaris, several BSDs and I believe Linux and maybe even Windows that was caused by a misplaced comma (or a similar seemingly innocuous mistake) in an Intel architecture document, I believe.